# Can't seem to Embolden or Italicize my links

Tags: overleaf

[image]

I am trying to build my Resume on Overleaf as of now. However, when I compile the code given in [this](https://gist.github.com/sd12832/e3f73562f71f99737ec00571e867746d) particular Gist, there seems to be a problem when I try to embolden or italicize these words.

Comment: This template doesn't set the fonts comprehensively so bold and italics are disabled, sigh. See https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/deedy-resume/sqdbztjjghvz#comment-2366304149

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).